# Unwanted JDBC messages ignore log4j configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j, h2

I have a problem with log4j or Spring or H2 configuration. I can't seem to find the culprit. My problem is that whilst log4j's logging configuration is very strict, I still get unwanted logs from some component in the system.

I use the Spring Framework and Hibernate to access a H2 database. One of those three produces logs that seem to be printed directly to `System.out`.

My log output:

```
12-12 18:41:08 jdbc[2]: 
/*SQL */SET DB_CLOSE_DELAY -1;
12-12 18:41:08 jdbc[2]: 
/**/Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=    2", "", "");
12-12 18:41:08 jdbc[2]: 
/*SQL #:1*/CALL LOCK_MODE();
12-12 18:41:08 database: disconnecting session #2
[main] WARN  org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver  - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
```

As you can see, the only proper logger line is the last one. My log4j configuration is this:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.h2=WARN
log4j.logger.org.java.sql=WARN

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

How do I find out who's producing those messages and how do I get him to shut up?

Comment: Did you check this [H2 logging information](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=logging&search=logging#other_logging)?

Comment: By the way, your title gave me the oposite impression: that you could not log messages, therefore I took the liberty to change it but you can adjust it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used slf4j and set TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4 in the jdbc-URL and now it works.

Comment: I know Spring and Hibernate play well with log4j therefore my suspect was H2. Since we found the culprit I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every Java software uses log4j.

In this case H2 generates a trace that can be controlled using slf4j as stated in [their documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=logging&search=logging#other_logging) in the section *"Using Other Logging APIs"*.